# Sort strings representing datetimes/timestamps

Tags: string, macos, perl, date

I have a set of strings that represent date-time  in the following format:
`1/30/2017 10:46:13 AM`
I would like to sort them and so I tried to convert them to actual dates as follows:

```
my $format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S";    
my $date1= Time::Piece->strptime($the_date_string, $format );
```

It gives an error in the parsing. How can I make this work?

Comment: What's the error? I think you're missing the _am/pm_ `%p` in your format.

Comment: @simbabque:`my @vals = _strptime($string, $format);` this line from Piece.pm breaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error I get when I run your code is

> garbage at end of string in strptime:  AM

You are missing the [period marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) for the `AM` in your string. Add `%p` to the pattern, which parses the local representation of *ante meridiem* or *post meridiem*. In your case, that's *AM* and *PM*.

```
my $format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p";
my $date1= Time::Piece->strptime('1/30/2017 10:46:13 AM', $format );
```

Comment: You were right about the missing `%p` and I also had the date with double quotes. Removing the quotes and adding the '%p` it seems to partially work. I.e. I get eventually the same error `Error parsing time` but I can't figure out what problem the passed in string has

Comment: @Jim Don't change your question after you've gotten answers. It invalidates the work people have done and makes it confusing for future visitors, since the answers no longer correspond to the question. Instead, please post a new question. You can include a link to the original question if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Ok. I will do that. You are right

Comment: @Jim When you do post your question, make sure to include a [mcve] (i.e. a complete program we can copy-and-paste and run on our own systems). The code in your edit was a good start, but it still wasn't copy-pasteable because you didn't show how `$date_string` was set, among other things. It would also help to know which OS you're on, since Time::Piece uses your system's locale for some things and that can cause platform-dependent breakages.